# Hibernate автосоздание базы

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

При работе с базой данных при помощи hibernate можно задавать параметр `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, который определяет, что делать с базой (создать, обновить и т.д.). Мне нужно, чтобы база сама создавалась. У меня для этого написан следующий код:

```
//Сервис для работы с базой
public class DBService {
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    public DBService(Configuration configuration){
        sessionFactory = createSessionFactory(configuration);
    }

    private static SessionFactory createSessionFactory(Configuration configuration){
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder();
        builder.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry = builder.build();
        return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    }
}

//Датасет
@Entity(name = "user")
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserDataSet implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;

    public UserDataSet(){}

    public UserDataSet(String login, String password, String email){
        this.login = login;
        this.password = password;
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

Ну и дальше я где-то еще в коде задаю конфигурацию для датабазного сервиса и создаю его:

```
Configuration configuration = new Configuration()
    .addAnnotatedClass(UserDataSet.class)
    .setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", "some_user")
    .setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", "some_password")
    .setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "false")
    .setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");

dbService = new DBService(configuration);
```

Вроде бы и все хорошо, все должно работать, но нет. Вылетает исключение, типа база не существует. Причем если ее создать руками, то все работает.

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'somedb'
```

По логике, при установке `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` в значение `create`, база должна создаться и все должно работать, но так не происходит. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Гибернейт не создает базу, он создает *схему*, т.е. структуру данных в существующей БД. Как вы можете видеть, вы задаете БД уже в JDBC URL, и создание базы выходит за пределы ответственности гибернейта - гибернейт оперирует уже внутри базы данных. Так или иначе, вам всегда нужно будет создавать саму БД руками.

Answer (score 1):

Может ответ и запоздалый, но добавь в конце `hibernate.connection.url` вот это: `?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true`.

Comment: А что означает `?` перед `createDatabaseIfNotExist`?

Comment: @0xdb Что будут указаны дополнительные параметры подключения. Например, помимо указанного выше параметра, можно отключить SSL написав `useSSL=false`. Объединяются несколько параметров знаком `&`, например: `<url>?useSSL=false&createDatabaseIfNotExsist=true`

Comment: Спасибо, всё так сложно в этом мире. Вы можете поравить вопрос и указать полную строчку кода.

Comment: Если честно, то не знаю что вы имеете ввиду под "поправить вопрос" (новичек я тут), но полная строчка кода будет такой: `setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?createDatabaseIfNotExsits=true")`, либо в файле `hibernate.cfg.xml` написать: `<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/somedb?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</property>`

Comment: Извините, я имел ввиду [поправить ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/658433/edit)